# Generic type not found in scope Rocket's router handler

Tags: json, generics, rust, traits, rust-rocket

What's the correct way to use generics in Rocket's router handler. I'm trying the following:

```
#[post("/handle_message", format = "json", data = "<json_message>")]
pub async fn handle_message<G>(
    session: &State<Arc<SessionState>>,
    peer_state: &State<Arc<PeerState>>,
    json_message: Json<models::JsonMessage<G>>,
    cfg: &State<ReloadableConfig>,
)
where
    G: Group + GroupEncoding + Default + Serialize,
{
    trace!("Handling POST /handle_message");
    let cfg = cfg.load_full();
    session.handle_message(json_message.message.clone());
}
```

I'm getting the compiler error: `cannot find type G in this scope not found in this scope`

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have a generic request handler? What would that even mean? Which monomorphised version of this function should be  chosen by the compiler in router?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I'm not sure about that. Maybe then it isn't possible to use Generics in the request handler

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with using the generic parameter `G`? What do you intend `G` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently have generic request handlers in Rocket.

This is (sadly) a limitation of the type system in Rust and has been discussed by Sergio in [this github issue](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/408).